# Ahlfors Complex Integration

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

This  is  my  opinion  on the  question.  Is  true  or  not? If  not  what  is  the  useful
solution?  Which  way  is  more  useful?

Comment: I wouldn't call this an "opinion", but rather an attempt at solving the problem!

Comment: :)  thank u  Patrick  Da  silva.  I  love  to  attempt  good  questions. but  maybe  it  is  easy  for  u  or  other  people. I  got  very  bad  education  from  undergraduate  unfortunately  and  that  why  i  am  happy  when  i  solve  the  problem  myself

Comment: No I mean your attempt is perfectly fine, I was only commenting the choice of words! Don't worry, it's all good :)

Comment: :) thanks for  positivity

Answer (score 0):

It follows from the original inequality that the logarithm of $f(z)$ is single-valued in the domain $\Omega$ and hence the integral of its differential along any closed curve is zero.

Comment: My  opinion  is  wrong?  or  not  Professor

Comment: No it is not wrong, you actually do the same thing without mentioning the logarithm.

Comment: Ohh  thank  you  i  am  feeling  happy  that  i  solved  myself  :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mu(t) = f\circ\gamma(t)$. Then
$$
         \int_{\mu}\frac{dw}{w} = \int_{\gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\,dz\;.
$$
The curve $\mu$ satisfies $|\mu(w)-1| < 1$, which means that the curve $\mu$ lies in the open unit ball centered at $1$. In this region, $1/w$ has a holomorphic antiderivative and, so, the integral on the far left is $0$.